# Cant pass null values to SqlServer from VB.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

Im using VB.net to control a DevExpress report object, i currently have a function that handles the data of said report, and when i run it the reports data comes back completely blank. When i run SQL Server Profiler i can see the command `exec dbo.sp_Get_CompanyTime @intCompanyID=1,@dteStart=NULL,@dteEnd=NULL,@strUserID=N'',@intCustomerID=1,@intProjectID=1` is ran when the report is called, returning no data at all because there UserID doesnt match anything, same for customer ID and project ID. The problem im facing is that in VB i have

```
Dim spcomptime As dsReporting.sp_Get_CompanyTimeDataTable = New dsReporting.sp_Get_CompanyTimeDataTable
Dim OpenDate As Nullable(Of DateTime)
Dim CloseDate As Nullable(Of DateTime)
Dim clientId As Nullable(Of Integer)
Dim cusId As Nullable(Of Integer)
Dim proID As Nullable(Of Integer)

Sp_Get_CompanyTimeTableAdapter.Fill(spcomptime, 1, OpenDate, CloseDate, clientId, cusId, proID)
```

which as you can hopefully see it should be passing null values for everything past the first 2 parameters! ive tried using DBNull.value as suggested elsewhere, but it tells me it cannot be converted to type "Integer?".
Somebody help me i've been trying to solve this for what feels like an age.

Comment: I think the answer is going to lie in the defintion of `Sp_Get_CompanyTimeTableAdapter`, you will need to determine if a value is null when adding the parameter to the SqlCommand, if it is null add `DBNull.Value` as the value, otherwise use the actual value.

Comment: One of the parameters are not of type integer that it is trying to convert it to. Check your parameters that are supposed to be of type integer.

Comment: spcomptime, clientId, cusId, proID - One of these most def are empty or not integer type and there it is failing.

Comment: @KayNelson No theyre all correct